# Phonegap app open in browser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Actually i am developing my first phonegap application . I want to know that the application developed in the phonegap opens in the web browser ? 
because phonegap framework contained phonegap.js , cordova.js and other javascripts . So only the web browser understands the javascript . it means to phonegap app needs a web browser i the phone to execute ?

Comment: Phonegap applications are not displayed in the browser app, but they are essentially just web pages. They are displayed in a native app with a component called `WebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap apps don't run in a browser, they are built to act like a native app and need to be downloaded, will have an icon, etc...

"Cordova is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use standard web technologies such as HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development, avoiding each mobile platforms' native development language. Applications execute within wrappers targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API bindings to access each device's sensors, data, and network status."

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview

Answer (score 0):

Well, Phonegap is not exactly using the phone browser, it's using a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) which is an HTML/CSS/JS rendering engine without the UI.

The WebView (on Android) is a part of the operating system, so even if you don't have the default browser installed, your app will still work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you're programming your application solely for Apache Cordova. For instance if you only use the Media plugin to do your audio, it will only work on Cordova. However if you program the application so that it has **fallbacks** for when it can't find the Media plugin, so that it chooses to use Web Audio API or HTML5 Audio instead, then it will work on both.

[image]

Aside from hosting the `www` folder of your application locally and running it on a desktop browsers, there is also a prototype emulator called Ripple which you could try.

http://emulate.phonegap.com/